# Importing module from source (google play licensing) doesn't actually import anything

Tags: java, android, android-studio, licensing, android-lvl

I am following this answer in order to setup Google Play Licensing: [Google Play Licencing for an Android app in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852617/google-play-licencing-for-an-android-app-in-android-studio?fbclid=IwAR3JJ4fm9Jm-Q8aifuQlfPOaMfgi32IvESqANpkvzIl-lEtKibADds7K47E)

Everything perfect until **.10**
However when I finish importing the module I don't have any module/folder in my project. I tried to check in the path of my android studio project and there is a folder with the module name I've chosen but it's empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why but when you download this library using the SDK manager then the `build.gradle` of the library is missing. And so you can't import it.

Please download the code from the git repository directly. Also note that this is the official way to download the library as described under https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.

You can use the `git` command or download it using the browser. You can find the repo under https://github.com/google/play-licensing. Download/extract it to an folder which is **not** inside your Android project.

If you don't have git select the green button and then select `Download ZIP`. Extract the ZIP to a folder which is **not** in your Android project folder.

Now open your Android Studio project and click `File > New > Import Module...`. Select the `lvl_library` folder of the library.

If it asks you select that you want to trust the library.

You are done.

Please note when there are updates for this library you have to do it manually. Close Android Studio. Delete `lvl_library` from your project. Copy the new `lvl_library` to your project. Done.

Comment: You would be able to help me to convert that kotlin code to java?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75617277/converting-rough-implementation-of-google-play-licensing-api-from-kotlin-to-java

Comment: Maybe someone gets help from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77162918/how-to-fix-plugin-id-com-android-application-version-8-1-1-apply-false/77864338#comment137513622_77864338) as well.