# How to fix Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

First, I create new project and built this successfully. And then I am trying to add OpenCV module to Android Studio. When I built this project, it display this fault.

```
Build file 'D:\MATERIAL\Android\TestOpencv\build.gradle.kts' line: 2

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository ...
at Program.execute(Unknown Source)...
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:125)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)...
```

In addition to that, when I import module OpenCV with Java folder, push Finish --> The screen displays "IDE error occurred".

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.toPath()" because "this.mySdkLocation" is null
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.getBuildToolsVersion(GradleImport.java:1123)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.createModuleBuildGradle(GradleImport.java:1013)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.exportModule(GradleImport.java:958)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.GradleImport.exportProject(GradleImport.java:823)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.AdtImportBuilder.lambda$commit$0(AdtImportBuilder.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$1.run(CoreProgressManager.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:429)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressSynchronously$9(CoreProgressManager.java:513)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:377)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:524)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:248)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.AdtImportBuilder.commit(AdtImportBuilder.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.adtimport.AdtModuleImporter.importProjects(AdtModuleImporter.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.importing.SourceToGradleModuleModel$handleFinished$$inlined$runWriteAction$1.compute(actions.kt:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runWriteAction$10(ApplicationImpl.java:989)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:989)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.importing.SourceToGradleModuleModel.handleFinished(SourceToGradleModuleModel.kt:83)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:411)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:339)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:350)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1815)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:753)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:191)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:236)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1080)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:743)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:467)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1676)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1634)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.actions.AndroidImportModuleAction.actionPerformed(AndroidImportModuleAction.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:327)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:306)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:350)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:306)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$performAction$5(ActionMenuItem.java:296)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:289)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$new$0(ActionMenuItem.java:64)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$4(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:526)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:558)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6656)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6421)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5026)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4854)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:790)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:763)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:761)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:831)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:753)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

I have learnt how to develop android application by Android Studio. How do I can fix it? Thank you for watching.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after importing a module from a project to another one. I'm not sure if the causes of the problems are the same, but I'll write my answer anyway in case someone will have my same problem.

I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4. When Importing the module, Android Studio creates a setting.gradle file, in the project folder, where there is the include to the new module (and only that) instead of adding it to the already existing settings.gradle.kts file. Most probably the compiler uses this new file and ignores the settings.gradle.kts where there are the repositories, so the error occurs (he can't find the plugin because there are no repository).

I've solved it just removing the setting.gradle and adding the include in the settings.gradle.kts file.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. This solved it for me. Android Studio creates a new file `settings.gradle` and puts `include ':lvl_library'` in it. Delete that file and put `include(":lvl_library")` in file `settings.gradle.kts`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error
I added:
id("com.android.library") version "8.1.0" apply false

project was built successfully
maybe it'll help you
see https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

2 Answers help my issue resolved when we integrated native template ads then after importing module my application gradle failed again and again we searched solution for this in everywhere but did not resolved my issue after followed this 2 answer of ms ? then my issue resolved thinks

I had the same problem after importing a module from a project to another one. I'm not sure if the causes of the problems are the same, but I'll write my answer anyway in case someone will have my same problem.

I'm using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1. When Importing the module, Android Studio creates a setting.gradle file, in the project folder, where there is the include to the new module (and only that) instead of adding it to the already existing settings.gradle.kts file. Most probably the compiler uses this new file and ignores the settings.gradle.kts where there are the repositories, so the error occurs (he can't find the plugin because there are no repository).

I've solved it just removing the setting.gradle and adding the include in the settings.gradle.kts file.